# Difference between v4 and v13 suport library in Android

Tags: android, android-support-library

Hello I was checking support library page on android doc where I found v13 library also. I use v4 in my projects.

I understood that v4 is required If I set the minSDKVersion between 4-12 and If I set it to >=13 then I should use v13 support library.

### Question

What is the use of support library v13 if we have already native `Fragment` classes if I set minSDKVersion to 13 because native `Fragment` is already from API 11 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html.

and Why they divided it into v4 and v13 if we have all features of v13 in v4 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is use of support library v13 if we have already native Fragment classes

You may not want to use the native `Fragment` classes. For example, *nested* fragments was only added to the native `Fragment` classes in API Level 17 -- if you wanted nested fragments on older devices, you have to use the backport.

> Why they divided it into v4 and v13 if we have all features of v13 in v4 ?

Not every class in `support-v13` works back to API Level 4. Notably, `support-v13` has implementations of `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` that work with native fragments. `support-v13` is a superset, not identical to, `support-v4`.

Comment: thanks again :) FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter aren't available in native SDK ?

Comment: Here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html it's already in v4 android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter. What do you mean of "work with native fragments"

Comment: @Williams: "FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter aren't available in native SDK?" -- correct, because `ViewPager` is not in the core SDK. "it's already in v4" -- that is the `support-v4` edition. There is *also* a *separate* `support-v13` edition of those classes, such as `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`. That version of the class uses `android.app.Fragment` for the pages, whereas the `support-v4` edition uses `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` for the pages.

Comment: I understood but now question is what is the difference between native and support `Fragment` class. I see that they are now focusing on native `Fragment` from v13. Is something not there in support `Fragment` that is only in native `Fragment` ?

Comment: @Williams: The support package's backport of fragments contains everything from the latest version of Android's edition of fragments. As I noted in my answer, the support package's backport of fragments contains *more things* than do some of the earlier native editions of fragments.

Comment: Okay thanks again :). I'm note sure about nested fragment ? can you please share doc link which classes have added in API level 17 and use of them ?

Comment: Already accepted answer +1. Always helpful. Thank you so much but please answer of my last question which I asked in comments.

Comment: @Williams: Information about what is new in any Android release is found in the documentation, such as: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html